# How to get code completetion for PHP objects in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, phpstorm, code-completion

I have an object within PHP with many properties that I assign to smarty.

Is it possible within the smarty template to get code completion for this object? 
This would improve programming speed and reduces typo errors.

I use PHPStorm 8.0.1 with smarty 3.1.21

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is no way to tell which smarty variable has which type ATM.

Comment: Thanks, I found a feature request at JetBrains Issues tracker that is not resolved yet :(
 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11879#tab=Comments